# Difference between "游泳" and "游水"

Tags: meaning, mandarin, usage, vocabulary

I've been learning with a course, and one of the lessons said: **这个男人在游泳**, but the same sentence with a dog was: **这只狗在游水**.

I presume that both were doing the same thing: swimming. So, can I use **游泳** with animals and **游水** with persons? What is the difference between them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same, you can also say

> 这只狗在游泳 or 这个男人在游水

The only difference is, 游水 is not commonly used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

游水 is mainly a colloquial Cantonese term  http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/1332/

> 游水
>
> /jau4 seoi2 /  (jyutping)
>
> swim, swimming. Mand.: 游泳
>
> *the entry of 游水 doesn't even include a Mandarin pinyin for it*

Also logically, you can swim (游泳) in any liquid ; while 游水 specifically means swim in water, but even Cantonese ignore it, since it is very rare that someone swim in a liquid other than water

Comment: 游水 is in two Mandarin dictionnaries: ABC and 现代汉语规范词典.

Answer (score 1):

游泳 can be both formal and informal.

游水 is informal.

for example, a sign reads "NO SWIMMING" can only be translated as "禁止游泳"。